# Does the following sentence make sense?

Tags: usage, translation

I have been trying to translate some Chinese text into English using google translate. Since google translate sometimes gives poor translations, I would like to seek your help to ensure that the English version is correct.

Does the following sentence makes sense? Is there a better way to say it?

> During the Cold War, the United States and the Soviet Union **blocked each other**

The Chinese text is

> 冷戰期間，美國和蘇聯**亙相封鎖**

If the sentence is correct, would you please tell me what you understand by the terms in boldface? If the sentence is incorrect, would you please suggest terms to replace the terms in boldface? Thank you.

Comment: It's ok to include the non-English version, but your question (and the answers) should not rely on it. As I've explained in previous comments (please refer to them), translation and proofreading requests are off-topic. If you could [edit] your post to explain the intended meaning, then we could assist you with finding a proper phrasing. Also, telling us why you think your phrasing is wrong would be helpful. See [Details, Please](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/439/36187) and the [Contributor's Guide (Asking)](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4785/36187) for more tips and examples.

Answer (score 2):

I think 'blocked' seems too generic if there are no elaborations.  You may consider 'boycotted'.

'During the Cold War, the United States and the Soviet Union "boycotted" each other.'